# Auto Size Main Window

Tags: go, electron

I am creating an app using [Go-Astilectron](https://github.com/asticode/go-astilectron) (an Electron framework for Go).

My app has a frameless and transparent window that should be resized depending on its content. As far as I could tell, I am obligated to set the `width` and `height` properties of a Window in Electron, otherwise it will default to 800x600.

What I would like to know is if there is a way for Electron to automatically resize the window based on its content.

I could use a "One Size Fits All" approach, but since my window is frameless and transparent, some parts of it will eventually be on top of other things, and since there is not click through, the user will get confused thinking that he is clicking on some other application, when he is actually clicking on my app.

Here is my code to create the window:

```
var w *astilectron.Window

log.Debug("Starting astilectron...")
window := []*bootstrap.Window{{
    Homepage: "http://localhost:3000",
    Adapter: func(i *astilectron.Window) {
        w = i
    },
    Options: &astilectron.WindowOptions{
        MinHeight:          astilectron.PtrInt(50),
        MinWidth:           astilectron.PtrInt(50),
        AlwaysOnTop:         astilectron.PtrBool(true),
        Transparent:         astilectron.PtrBool(true),
        Closable:            astilectron.PtrBool(false),
        Minimizable:         astilectron.PtrBool(false),
        Frame:                   astilectron.PtrBool(false),
        Movable:                 astilectron.PtrBool(true),
        SkipTaskbar:         astilectron.PtrBool(false),
        Resizable:           astilectron.PtrBool(false),
    },
}}

go func() {
    err := bootstrap.Run(bootstrap.Options{
        Windows: window,
        Debug: true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("Error with Astilectron")
    }
}()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `UseContentSize: astilectron.PtrBool(true)`.

`UseContentSize` Resizes the window according to how big the page is. This is what it says in the documentation:

> The width and height would be used as web page's size, which means the actual window's size will include window frame's size and be slightly larger. Default is false.

[Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)

Comment: Hi, I tried to set this flag on my window, but it still doesn't work. the window size defaults to 800x600. Note: I tried it both with and without a `Width` and `Height` set.

Comment: the answer is wrong. UseContentSize just defines whether widths and height setting set the whole window size or just the window content size. But i can understand why the setting name is confusing.

Answer (score -2):

try to do something like this

```
  const { screen } = require('electron');
  const size = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   width: size.width,
  height: size.height
});
```

Hope it will work .

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think that this will work, since I am creating my window in Go, not in Javascript... I will update my question.

Comment: `const size = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;`  

The code above actually will fill the whole screen!